# Why is it sufficient for a normal to only be orthogonal to 2 vectors on a plane instead of 3?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

The following is an excerpt from my textbook:

> It is clear geometrically that there is a unique plane containing any 3 points $A,B$ and $C$ that are not all on a line. In determining the equation of this plane, the problem is finding a normal vector for the plane. Since any nonzero vector which is orthogonal to both $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$ will do as a normal, $\dots$

Why don't we need to consider the vector $\overrightarrow{BC}$ too? Or is it sufficient to just choose any two of the 3 possible vectors that we can create given points $A,B$ and $C$? How do I prove this?

Comment: Hint: if something is orthogonal to the set of vectors, it'll be orthogonal to their span too.

Comment: You have to observe that 3 points are needed to determine a plane,  but only 2 line segments $AB, AC$ are needed to determine the plane and hence the normal to these two vectors is sufficient. Resulting vector will also be orthogonal to $BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that 3 points give a unique plane.
Similarly 2 vectors having a common point also give a unique plane.
Hence you can use $\overrightarrow{BA}$,$\overrightarrow{BC}$ or $\overrightarrow{CA}$,$\overrightarrow{CB}$ as well